# load more posts using $wpdb get_result

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

am trying get posts via $wpdb because there is not other way for the query
but am having a problem making a load more with ajax
help!
this is my current pagination

```
$total_page = ceil( $total_posts / $posts_per_page); // Calculate Total pages

$prev_arrow = is_rtl() ? '&rarr;' : '&larr;';
$next_arrow = is_rtl() ? '&larr;' : '&rarr;';
$big = 8888888; // need an unlikely integer
if( $total_page > 1 )  {
     if( !$current_page = get_query_var('paged') )
         $current_page = 1;
     if( get_option('permalink_structure') ) {
         $format = 'page/%#%/';
     } else {
         $format = '&paged=%#%';
     }?>
        <div class="navigation">
            <p class="nav-older"><?php next_posts_link( __( '&larr; Older posts', 'p2' ) ); ?></p>
            <p class="nav-newer"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts &rarr;', 'p2' ) ); ?></p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You need to explain what the problem actually _is_, instead of just stating that you have one.

Comment: the problem is i have a query by qet_result that get posts but i need to put load more a button with ajax but i see that work only with wb_query

Comment: They aren’t that much different, and take pretty much the same parameters. With the global query you get basic pagination built-in already though (in terms of the neccessary parameters getting passed to it), with get_posts you will likely have to do that yourself. Either way, the code you have shown us is only to create the pagination _menu_, and assumes that the numbers are already know at this point, so that isn’t of much help here.

Comment: would you help me with 5 usd or 10 thanks (: